# what is executed first in c?

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50

I am trying to write a function that applies a sepia filter to the images,

```
    void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
    {
         for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
         {
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
            {
                int r = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
                int g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                int b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

                image[i][j].rgbtRed =  round((0.393 * r) + (0.769 * g) + (0.189 * b));
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen =  round((0.349 * r) + (0.686 * g) + (0.168 * b));
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((0.272 * r) + (0.534 * g) + (0.131 * b));


                if(image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255)
                {
                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
                }

                if(image[i][j].rgbtGreen > 255)
                {
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
                }

                if(image[i][j].rgbtBlue > 255)
                {
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

when I used this code, it does not raise any error, but the if conditions do not work at all, and the resulting image has many creepy pixels.

but when I used intermediate variables like this code below:

```
    void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
    {
        for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
            {
                int r = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
                int g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                int b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

                int sr =  round((0.393 * r) + (0.769 * g) + (0.189 * b));
                int sg =  round((0.349 * r) + (0.686 * g) + (0.168 * b));
                int sb = round((0.272 * r) + (0.534 * g) + (0.131 * b));


                if(sr > 255)
                {
                    sr = 255;
                }

                if(sg > 255)
                {
                    sg = 255;
                }

                if(sb > 255)
                {
                   sb = 255;
                }

                image[i][j].rgbtRed = sr;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sg;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sb;
            }
         }
     }
```

the if statements worked perfectly.

my question is **what is wrong in the first code that makes the if statements don't work?**

Comment: What is the type `RGBTRIPLE`?  If it contains values of type `char` or `short`, you may be getting premature truncation or overflow or something, which you don't get when declaring the intermediate `int sr, sg, sb` values.

Comment: Debug your programs before posting to Stack Overflow. Simply printing the values used in the `if` statements would have revealed the problem.

Comment: the goal of the ' if ' statements is to prevent any color value from being more than 255, but what happens when using the first code is that the if statements do not detect any value higher than 255, and values remain higher than 255 and the resulting image is creepy.

Comment: I already used 'printf'  inside the if statement in the first code, and it does not detect any value higher than 255, but clearly there are values higher than 255.

Comment: *what happens when using the first code is...* Yes, we get that.  Now, in the first code, what is the type of `image[i][j].rgbtRed`?

Comment: *clearly there are values higher than 255* "Clearly? Based on what?  Based on what you *think* the value is, or on what `printf` says the value actually is?

Comment: eight-bit unsigned integers

Comment: clearly based on the resulting image, and based on that if the formula is applied to bright colors it will definitely result in values greater than 255, and based on using the second code and using printf in it.

Comment: @Ahmedabo-alata Okay, I thought you were saying something else, sorry.  Anyway, problem solved now, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255` is never true as `.rgbtRed` is 8-bit.  Use an `int` to save the sum.

Comment: thanks a lot.  now I can understand the reason  why the first code is not working

Answer (score 0):

The structure members are eight-bit unsigned integers. When you assign to them, values over 255 are lost. (They are wrapped modulo 256.)

When you assign to the intermediate `int` variables, they retain the full values.